# How to make Postgres to manage the table’s lifecycle in a django project

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to create a project using django with a populated database, my problem is when I try to create a new object I get this error duplicate key value violates unique constraint, because the database is already populated, what can I do to change it to make Postgres manage it or django to get the right sequence?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Are you getting the errors because Django tries to create tables that already exist in your database? If so, you can add `managed = False` to your model's `Meta` class and Django will not touch the database for this model. It will then be your own responsibility to keep your tables up to date with your Django models.

See the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#managed .

Comment: sorry for my question, That is exactly what I wanted thanks a lot

Comment: @DiogoSilva you don't have to apologize :) just be prepared for people asking you for more explanation if your question is not immediately clear.